# Left recursion mutally in antlr 3

Tags: recursion, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I try to parsing the grammar in the **antlr 3** , but i have a problem with the left recursion , and I am a beginner in parsing grammar.

Comment: You have to rewrite your grammar in order to remove the left recursion. Fortunately, there is an algorithm for that. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion, Section Removing all left recursions.

Comment: The transformation that you have to make: `b -> ID; b -> NUM; b -> -NUM; b->e`. The same for e,t f. Then you apply the algorithm. The problem is with `b->e; (e -> t; e -> t a t); (t -> f, t -> t m f); t -> b`. Think of the arrow as 'gives'. And when you apply the algorithm b,e,t,f,a,m are non terminal characters.

Comment: Step 1: rewrite the rules in order to show implicit recursions.

Comment: Step 2: Now you have explicit recursions, apply the logic explained "Removing direct left recursion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the roules **b, e, t, f** are referencing each other without consuming any input - e.g. a number could be accepted by multiple sequences:

```
b -> NUM
b -> e -> t -> f -> b -> NUM
...
```

the cycle you have there probably is meant to express a sub-expression - what's missing there then are parentheses:

```
start   : e;
e       : t (a t)*;
t       : f (m f)*;
f       : ID | NUM | '-'NUM | '(' e ')';
a       : '+' | '-';
m       : '*' | '/';
```

(I also changed `e : t | t a t` to `e : t | e a t` to allow `1 + 2 + 3`)

Comment: `e       : t | e a t;` and `t       : f | t m f ;` are still left recursive: something ANTLR 3 cannot handle.

Comment: @BartKiers my bad, forgot about that one. Edited.

Comment: Yup, that looks ANTLR3 compatible!